# How to write query in codeigniter for group_concat and concat with replace for table column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting  column value   with comma separated and inside single quote  which is working fine in phpmyadmin and getting output ,but I want to write in codeigniter using $this->db->query() but getting some error beacuse of single quotes
So how to write this query in codeigniter format

```
Query in codeigniter:   // Not working 

$this->db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_id, ",", "','") , "'")) 
as listed_id FROM user_data"); //  user_id is column name

Query in phpmyadmin:   //working

GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_id, ",", "','") , "'"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string is not valid because this can be recognized as a string:

```
"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT("
```

and the rest does not make sense:

```
'", REPLACE(user_id, ",", "','") , "'")) as listed_id FROM user_data"
```

You should escape quotation marks when they are within quotation marks of the same kind:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(\"'\", REPLACE(user_id,
\",\", \"','\") , \"'\")) as listed_id FROM user_data");
```